# Modify nested object and then return the modified parent object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I've got this function

```
function save(value, ...props)
{
    var record;
    var allRecords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
    record = allRecords;
    for (var prop of props)
    {
        record = record[prop];
    }
    record = value;
    window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(allRecords));
}
```

whose job is to save a bunch of data in the window.localStorage. However, since JavaScript is a 'reference by value' language, modifying `record` doesn't affect the parent object (`allRecords`). So, how can I iterate throughout the storage object, modifying one its children, and then save the modified parent object?

Comment: Note that you are AFAICT describing a lens. Also, you have the most pandering user name I've ever *seen*. https://medium.com/javascript-inside/an-introduction-into-lenses-in-javascript-e494948d1ea5#.20hn1a91i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the parent object:

```
function save(value, ...props)
{
  var record = allRecords = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
  var parent=record;
  for (var prop of props)
  {
      parent=record;//store before modifying, so keep the parent
      record = record[prop];
  }

 parent[prop]= value;
 window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify((allRecords));
 return parent;
}
```

However you now that your function goes "deep" into the object ( just saying):

```
save("hi","a","b","c");//will save like this
a={
   b={
     c="hi";
   }
}
```

Another possibility would be stop the loop right before the last iteration, then do record[prop]=value.

1.How objects are stored:
Objects are stored by pointer. So in memory it looks like this (pseudocode):

```
//a memory location holding an object
432:
 val1:1
 val2:2
```

If you say the name of the object is a, a is stored like this:

```
a = location:432
```

if you copy it, for example with b=a, just the pointer is copied not the object:

```
a = location:432
b = location:432
```

If you change sth in the object a, it will in fact change the object at location 432, therefore b is changed to.
Objects in Objects look the same:

```
//another obj
100:
   obj1:  location:432 //our pointer to the object
```

So our for loop (lets stay at the upper save example) will follow pointer to an object, get a property holding a pointer, than follow this pointer to another object ( a-> b -> c). These objects are stored somewhere in the mem. The JSON.stringify function does deep copy. So it follows every pointer and puts every necessary info into one string ( object a b and c).

2. "Why does your code work and mys not?":

What you do

```
value=obj[key];
value="new";
```

What i do:

```
obj[key]="new";
```

But thats the same isnt it? NOPE. Lets look at the data in memory:

```
  //you
 //before
value:undefined
obj:
    key:"old"

//copying
value:"old"
obj:
     key:"old"

//changing

value:"new"
obj:
      key:"old" //never changed...
```

Comment: You are setting data to allRecords, but you haven't declared it. What did you mean to do there?

Comment: right. ive shortified the upper code without looking at the under one...

Comment: Oh my gosh. How can it works??? It's over my understanding. You... copy the master object, then go deeper inside... modify... and suddenly the master object gets modified too. What's under the hood here? Why does your snippet work and mine does not?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Good explanation